# 320 and Up Framework - What's the 600 size for?

Tags: css, responsive-design

[320 and up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/) has for style sheets: default,  480, 600, 768, 992 and 1382px

- The default is for iPhone-style devices in portrait mode
- 480 is for iPhone-style devices in landscape mode
- 768 is for iPad-style tablets in landscape portrait mode
- 992 is for desktop/landscape tablets
- 1382 is for desktop

Which device is 600px wide and what would the height be of a device.

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I have looked around at the sizes of popular devices and cannot find any that are 600px wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kindle Fire is 600x1024 Portrait and 1024x600 landscape.  I only found it when playing with a website that really helps when testing http://www.responsinator.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was a very helpful answer: The link you posted is great and provides access to several awesome sources. Thank you very much!